# how to store a dom var for several functions in js?

Tags: javascript, mootools

there are several function will have to get the dom $$('.box')[0] ,
I don't want to let box to be a glabal var, and I don't want to let js seek the 
dom every time . and I don't want to run $$('.box')[0] when user not run these functions.
how to store the box var?
[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* ------- 
        there are several function will have to get the dom $$('.box')[0] ,
        I don't want to let box to be a glabal var, and I don't want to let js seek the 
        dom every time . and I don't want to run $$('.box')[0] when user not run these functions.
        how to store the box var?
    ------- */
    function a(){
        var box = $$('.box')[0];
        //...
    }
    function b(){
        var box = $$('.box')[0];
        //...
    }
    //...
</script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should really use a closure then.

```
(function(scope){

    var box = box document.getElement('.box'); // same as $$()[0], returns first match

    scope.a = function(){
        return box;
    };

    scope.b = function(){
        box;
    };

}(this)); // whatever object, eg, window or a namespace

box; // reference error.
this.a(); // box element object
```

box will remain private and also static, i.e. it wont get refreshed anymore.

you can do it so it's referenced and cached once when needed:

```
(function(scope){
    var box;

    scope.a = function(){
        box = box || document.getElement('.box');
        return box;
    };

    scope.b = function(){
        // alt syntax;
        box || (box = document.getElement('.box'));
        return box;
    };

}(this)); // whatever object, eg, window or a namespace
```

this way, calling either method will cache box and make it available for any of the methods in the closure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this would help, but you could separate the getting of it into a function and only allow it to be executed once. I forget where I got this function from, but it's useful for only allowing a function to run once (and every other time it's called, just return the value):

```
function once(func) {
    // Function wrapper to only allow a function, *func*, to be called once.

    var ran = false, ret = undefined;
    return function () {
        if (ran) {
            return ret;
        }
        ran = true;
        ret = func.apply(this, arguments);
        return ret;
    };
}
```

So I would use it like:

```
var getBox = once(function () {
    return $$('.box')[0];
});
```

And just always use `getBox()` when you want to get the element. Only the first time you call it will the DOM be searched. Every time after that, it'll just return the box.

While this might "help", it is just as good as creating a global variable, so I'm not exactly sure what you expect as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

try creating a pseusdo namespace, and within it, an application cache

```
var mySpace = (function(){
    var appcache = {};
    function a(){
        var box = appcache.box0 
                   || (appcache.box0 = $$('.box')[0], appcache.box0);
        //...
    }
    function b(){
        var box = appcache.box0 
                   || (appcache.box0 = $$('.box')[0], appcache.box0);
        //...
    }
    return {a: a, b: b};
}());
// usage: you can call a or b like
mySpace.a();
mySpace.b();
```

Answer (score 1):

declare your `box` variable out of the scope of functions

```
var box = "";

function a(){
      if(box != "" || box != undefined || box != 'undefined')
        alert(box +" from a");
      else
        box = $$('.box')[0];       
    }

function b(){
      if(box != "" || box != undefined || box != 'undefined')
        alert(box + " from b");
      else
        box = $$('.box')[0];        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about performance, just give your box an id and call it using

```
var  element = null;

function myFun(){
if(!element)
    element = $('#myId');
//Do logic
}
```